# Tensorboard showing different mean square value

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to visualise simple linear regression in Tensorboard. Below is the code. But the value I am seeing in the console is not matching with the value shown in the tensorboard graph at all.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, n+1), name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name="y")
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n+1, batch_size], -1.0, 1.0), name="theta")
global_step = tf.Variable(0,name='global_step',trainable=False)
y_pred = tf.matmul(X, theta, name="predictions")
error = y_pred - y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name='mse')
optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(mse, global_step=global_step)
mse_summary = tf.summary.scalar('MSE', mse)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, tf.get_default_graph())


init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:    
    sess.run(init)    
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs):
        for batch_index in range(n_batches):
            X_batch, y_batch= fetch_batch(epoch, batch_index, batch_size)
            if batch_index % 50 == 0 and batch_index != 0:
                _,summary_str = sess.run([training_op, summary_op],feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
                file_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step))
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE", sess.run(mse, feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})            
    best_theta = theta.eval()   
    file_writer.close()
```

In the console, I am getting the below messages:

```
Epoch 100 MSE 2.42409
Epoch 200 MSE 2.28097
Epoch 300 MSE 2.14192
Epoch 400 MSE 2.00997
Epoch 500 MSE 1.88537
Epoch 600 MSE 1.76792
Epoch 700 MSE 1.65733
Epoch 800 MSE 1.55331
Epoch 900 MSE 1.45556
model saved at step= 167832
```

and the tensorboard scalar plot for run is 
[image]

What I am able to interpret is the value of MSE is ranging from 6.* to 4.*. Or maybe I am missing something in the visualisation. I am not able to see curve near anywhere to mse at last epoch i.e. 1.4 or even at 100th epoch 2.42.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're doing in pseudo-code:

```
Load stuff
Initialise model
Begin EPOCH loop
    Begin BATCH loop
        Do training ops
        Store summary at intervals
    End BATCH loop
    Print MSE for an EPOCH
End EPOCH loop
```

You are mixing up EPOCH and BATCH results. So you are visualising the Batch results, but printing the Epoch results.

The MSE for each epoch can be different to the MSE from batches. Batch MSE is calculated for each 50 batch steps. But Epoch MSE is calculated after all the batch training operations have finished.

So the epoch MSE result is dependant on what happens to the model after **all** of the batch training ops. The final batch MSE *might* be similar to the epoch MSE, but it's not always the case.

Try some code like this and see what results you get (I might have made a mistake in the syntax, but you see what I'm getting at)

```
if epoch % 100 == 0:
    print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE", sess.run(mse, feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
    _,summary_str = sess.run(summary_op,feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
    file_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=tf.train.global_step(sess, global_step))
```

**A note on your data sets:**

Use separate data sets for training (batch training ops) and testing (epoch results). Don't reuse the batch training data to test the model. Else you're just retesting on the same data the model has been trained with. It's not being tested on a 'new' scenario... Which doesn't tell you anything useful and can lead to overfitting.